# How to find object in array of objects, whose nested array matches all the objects in a separate array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, matching

How to find object in array of objects, whose nested array matches all the objects in a separate array?

I have an array of **options** and an array of **productVariants**. I would like to find the **productVariant**  who's **selectedOptions** property matches all the **name** and **value** fields in an **option** array?

Types would look like this

```
const options: Array<{name: String, value: String}> 

const productVariants: Array<{selectedOptions: Array<{name: String, value: String, optionalFields?: String}>}>
```

Example of the data here:

```
const options = [{ name: “Format”, value: “Hardback” }, { name: “Colour”, value: “Pink” }, { name: “Size”, value: “Large” }]

const productVariants = [{selectedOptions: [{name: "Format", value: "Zine", optionalFields:”abc”},{name: "Colour", value: "Grey", optionalFields: ”abc”}]}, {selectedOptions: [{name: “Format”, value: "Zine", optionalFields:”abc”},{name: “Colour”, value: “Pink”, optionalFields: “abc”}]}]
```

My desired output would be to retrieve a single **productVariant** object whose **selectedOptions** array matches all the options in the options Array. The selectedOptions property of the variant can include the options (and can have more properties).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your sample data is not valid JavaScript/TS

Comment: Thank you. I have now updated the sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const isEquel = (obj1, obj2) => obj1.name === obj2.name && obj1.value === obj2.value;
const selectedOptions = [];
productVariants.map(productVariant => {
    const isMatch = options.every(option => productVariant.selectedOptions.some(selectedOption => isEquel(selectedOption, option)))
    if (isMatch) selectedOptions.push(productVariant);
});
```

Then the result is in `selectedOptions`

If you use lodash you can optimise this code

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works, but it matches all the productVariants that have at least one selectedOption. Is there a way to return the selected variant that match all the options in the selectedOptions array? To return the variant, I am using ```selectedOptions.push(productVariant)``` as the last line. Best

Comment: No problem , it should work for you now